# How to get value <span class="ng-binding">TestFolder</span> result should be TestFolder

Tags: protractor

```
<div class="file-folder-breadcrumbs-child-panel ng-hide" ng-show="isExpanded(root.full)">
     <!-- ngRepeat: child in root.nodes -->
        <div ng-repeat="child in root.nodes" class="ui-state-default filedrop file-folder-breadcrumbs-item-child ng-scope" ng-click="navigateToChild($event, child, root)">
           <span class="ng-binding">TestFolder</span>
         </div>
     <!-- end ngRepeat: child in root.nodes -->
 </div>
```

I am not able to get TestFolder by using:

```
const myDiv=element.all(by.repeater('item in currentPathNodes track by $index')).filter(item => item.element(by.className('ui-state-default btn btn-toolbar ng-scope'))).filter(item => item.element(by.className('file-folder-breadcrumbs-item-part name'))).filter(item => item.element(by.className('ng-binding')).getText().then(label => label === fileName));
console.log(myDiv);
return folderName;
```

please help

Comment: Edit your question, it's difficult to read and explain more to get help

Comment: 1. I edited your question. For your future benefits, it is more likely to get an answer if users can actually read the question properly. 2. You have too many problems already and lots of information still missing